# error obtained while executing python code

Tags: python

I've just executed the python code below on coding ground online:

```
miles = input('Enter a distance in miles:')
miles_float = float(miles)
kilometres = miles_float*1.609344
print ('That value in miles is: ')
print (kilometres)
```

And the error it's generated is:

```
Enter a distance in miles:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    miles = input('Enter a distance in miles:')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Kindly assist with debugging

Comment: There should be a option in the coding ground which you use stating "stdin" where you should enter the inputs before execution of the program

Comment: Using old Python 2? Update to 3!

Comment: Thanks. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to the STDIN tab and enter the input you want for your `input()` line. I.e. if I put `10` there, then your code outputs:

```
$python main.py
Enter a distance in miles:That value in miles is: 
16.09344
```